How to let an extension or tab use unlimited amount of RAM in browser
I have been using ChatGPT for a long time and I am wanting to keep offline copy of my prompts. I came across an extension called "ExportGPT" which lets me export my chat into a PDF, Word, Image, MD file or text. I mostly export in PDF however this makes use of a lot of memory and crashes the tab with "Error Code: Out of memory". I have observed that after almost 5500 MB of ram consumption by tab it crashes both on Chrome and Microsoft Edge. However, Microsoft Edge performances better as it sometimes allows about 10500 MB of RAM to be used. Is there any get around possible as fixing this can help me save my time.
On Microsoft Edge Whenever I got a alert saving "Your page isn't responding" I clicked on Wait for the page and this let the RAM usage go up to 10500 MB. I believe it's the RAM restrictions not letting it work efficiently.

Browsers often limit memory usage per tab or extension to prevent performance issues and crashes. This limit is intended to prevent system resource exhaustion, which can cause instability in the entire system. So, it’s not really feasible to have browser extensions or tabs use an unlimited amount of RAM. As alternative workaround, I can give you the following five suggestions to reduce crash:

Browser extensions are another area where you can reclaim some much-needed RAM. So you can try disabling or uninstalling unnecessary extensions.

You can navigate to Edge Settings>System and performance>Optimize Performance. Then turn on “Save resources with sleeping tabs” and “Fade sleeping tabs”.

Make sure your browser is up to date.

You can try contacting the author of the ExportGPT extension to optimize the extension

If your browser usage consistently requires more RAM, consider upgrading your system’s RAM. This will provide more resources for all applications, including your browser.


